# PM2 change cluster processes size at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

does anyone know if it is possible to change in NodeJS PM2 the number of cluster processes for an application at runtime?

regards
Philipp

Comment: To clarify, are you asking if it's possible to change the amount of cluster processes once you have started the app running?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `pm2 scale` to scale vertically the number of process at runtime, note that it only work with **cluster mode**.
Example :

- `pm2 scale APPNAME 2` will scale the process to exactly 2 instances.
- `pm2 scale APPNAME +2` will add two process.
- `pm2 scale APPNAME -1` will remove one process.

[source link](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/API.js#L1397)

Comment: Note that "pm2 scale APPNAME 2" will not add two processes, rather scale to a total of two processes. Use "+2" to add two processes. See my answer to scale using the Programmatic API too.

Answer (score 2):

specify pm2 settings in json format:

```
{
 "apps": [{
    "name": "server",
    "script" : "index.js",
    "instances": 2,
    "exec_mode: "cluster",
    "cwd": "/path/to/script"
 }]
}
```

start the server:

```
pm2 start application.json
```

suppose you want to add 2 more instances, just run the same command again:

```
pm2 start application.json
```

check the processes list:

```
pm2 list
```

to test that all 4 instances are run in cluster mode:

```
pm2 restart server
```

it will restart each of the 4 processes.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime (after the application is started), there are 2 ways to "scale" the application:

1) With the command line (documented [here](https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/) under "Scaling your cluster in realtime"), like this:

```
pm2 scale <app name> <n>
```

*Note that  can be a consistent number which the cluster will scale up or down to. It can also be an addition such as pm2 scale app +3 in which case 3 more workers will be added to the cluster.*

2) With the Programmatic API (docs are [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/#programmatic-api), but scale is not documented). As it's not documented, here's how you do it:

```
pm2.scale(<APPNAME>, <SCALE_TO>, errback)
```

Note that  is the number that will be scaled up or down to, not the number added or removed. Here's a full example of connecting to and scaling to 4 instances:

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');
pm2.connect(function (err) {
    pm2.scale('appname', 4, function(err, procs) {
        console.log('SCALE err: ', err);
        console.log('SCALE procs: ', procs);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and did not find any solution. To solve this problem i wrote a small plugin for PM2 which can help dynamically scale applications based on utilization demand. You can try and play with it https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-autoscale

Or just install it directly

```bash
pm2 install pm2-autoscale
```

When module detects that CPU utilisation is higher then expected it will start increasing instances to max CPUs-1 and if server has available free memory.

When module detects CPU utilization is decreasing it will stop useless instances.